# Expression has changed after it was checked - MatDialog Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have read several answers, and I have tried many but I can't seem to get this to work. In my angular 6 app, I try to open a MatDialog but I receive this error:

> ERROR Error: 
>   ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: 
>   Expression has changed after it was checked. 
>   Previous value: '@slideDialog: enter'. Current value: '@slideDialog: exit'.

When I debug the app and click the checkout button, the MatDialog opens and then after stepping through a few more lines it closes. When running the app without breakpoints, you never see the dialog open at all.

Here is the template file:

```
<div>
  <button id="cancelButton" mat-raised-button (click)="clearCart()">Cancel</button>
  <button id="checkoutButton" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openCheckoutDialog(dataSource)" [disabled]="isTableEmpty()">Checkout</button>
</div>
```

When I click the button with the id "checkoutButton" it calls `openCheckoutDialog()`

Here is my class where openCheckoutDialog is called:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shopping-cart',
  templateUrl: './shopping-cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shopping-cart.component.css']
})
export class ShoppingCartComponent implements OnInit {

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Item>;
  itemList: Item[] = [];

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  openCheckoutDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ReviewItemListComponent, {
      width: '250px',
      data: this.itemList
    });
    // this.cdr.detectChanges();

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
    });
    // this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

I have tried the `this.cdr.detectChanges()` in those 2 places above, but I would still receive the error.

Here is my ReviewItemListComponent template (dialog when the checkout button is clicked):

```
<div>
  <h1 mat-dialog-title>
    Are you sure?
  </h1>

  <mat-dialog-actions>
    <button tabindex="-1" mat-raised-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Cancel</button>
    <button tabindex="-1" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="confirm()">Confirm</button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
</div>
```

And here is the ReviewItemListComponent class:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { Item } from '../item';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-review-item-list',
  templateUrl: './review-item-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./review-item-list.component.css']
})
export class ReviewItemListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ReviewItemListComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Item[]) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  confirm(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

I'm not making any changes to data, which is what most of the questions & answers involve, so how do I resolve this problem regarding opening a MatDialog?

**Edit:**

Turns out I had pasted `this.dialogRef.close()` into the wrong method. In this case I put it inside of `ngOnInit()` when I was creating my review-item-list-component.ts file. So once I open it I close it. This still doesn't explain the error. What is so wrong about closing the recently opened dialog inside of `ngOnInit()`?

Comment: Odd - those are animation props. Check that the library is compatible with NG6.

Comment: There was a fairly [recent issue filed](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10705) for something very similar to this. Which I believe is actually related to this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15634). The work-around seems to be to wrap your dialog creation in a `setTimeout`

Comment: @bc1105 Check the edit section of my question

Comment: @Und3rTow I've tried timeouts, check out my edited question

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with closing the dialog in `ngOnInit`. The problem is that the view (dialog) is being modified during the change detection cycle.(which runs twice in dev mode - in prod you would not have this error) If you move `dialog.close()` into `ngAfterViewInit` I believe it should stop that error from being thrown.

Comment: 99% of `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` can be worked-around adding `changeDetectionRef.detectChanges()` on the parent.

Answer (score 7):

Use dialog close inside settimeout.

```
setTimeout(() => {    
    this.dialogRef.close();
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know, that your question can already be not actual, but anyway I will answer.
The problem is that you call `close` method in `ngOnInit` function.

Component doesn't keep up to end itself initialization, when you already call `close` method. Of course in this case, such error is called.

Please remove this calling in `ngOninit`, and write correct logic, I mean, write calling close method in separated method, which you'll call there, where it would be needed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Change *[mat-dialog-close]* or *[matDialogClose]* to *(click)* event. That's works for me.

***Update:***
I guess *[matDialogClose]* is now working as we expected.